# Why filled Dart list adds to all its elements?

Tags: arrays, list, dart

I have a simple code where I create a filled list of integer lists and add an integer to the first element of the list.

```
  List<List<int>> list = List<List<int>>.filled(2, []);
  list[0].add(1);
  print(list);
```

What I expect is: [[1],[]]
But in console I get: [[1], [1]]
I can't understand this behavior, can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely meant to use List.generate. The Dart documentation [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/List/List.filled.html) references this exact situation. By using filled you are explicitly stating that all of the elements have the same fill value.